# Am trying to determent the time/latency from os.system('ping') function on python

Tags: python, system

`import os import time for i in range(20): start = time.time() os.system('ping -n 1 {}'.format('google.com')) end = time.time()`
I tried this one but i the end - start is not efficient so am trying to get a solution on how to get the time from the commend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 def TicTocGenerator():
        # Generator that returns time differences
        ti = 0  # initial time
        tf = time.time()  # final time
        while True:
            ti = tf
            tf = time.time()
            yield tf - ti  # returns the time difference


    TicToc = TicTocGenerator()  # create an instance of the TicTocGen generator

    def toc(tempBool=True):
        # Prints the time difference yielded by generator instance TicToc
        tempTimeInterval = next(TicToc)
        if tempBool:
            print("Elapsed time: %f seconds.\n" % tempTimeInterval)
    
    
    def tic():
        # Records a time in TicToc, marks the beginning of a time interval
        toc(False)
    
    
    
    
    tic()
    #your code here
    toc()
```

but if you need ping statistics you can use:

```
from pythonping import ping

PingRes = ping(target=self.ip,timeout=3,count=3, verbose=True)
```